# how to make wget retry download if speed goes below certain threshold?

Tags: wget

I'm trying to download a large 2GB file with wget, but after a few minutes it seems to keep stalling.

I ^C it, and wget it again [with `--continue` option], and it starts downloading again.

Is there a way to automate retrying the download when it stops downloading? Thanks

Answer (score 24, accepted):

You could use the `--tries` option.

```
   --tries=number
       Set number of retries to number.  Specify 0 or inf for infinite
       retrying.  The default is to retry 20 times, with the exception of
       fatal errors like "connection refused" or "not found" (404), which
       are not retried.
```

So `--tries=0` should do the trick.

That, combined with `--read-timeout=seconds` too. The *seconds* refers to idle time: if, at any point in the download, no data is received for more than the specified number of seconds, reading fails and the download is restarted.

So the final command:

`wget -c --tries=0 --read-timeout=20 [URL]`

Comment: The problem is that wget doesn't quit.  It just keeps "downloading" at 0KB/s.. :(

Comment: Ok. Probably you could use `--read-timeout=seconds` instead. The "time" of this timeout refers to idle time: if, at any point in the download, no data is received for more than the specified number of seconds, reading fails and the download is restarted.  This option does not directly affect the duration of the entire download. Of course, the remote server may choose to terminate the connection sooner than this option requires.  The default read timeout is 900 seconds.

Comment: Yes!  That is it!  I must have read this long ago when I read the wget manual [most/all of it], and I went back and couldn't find it.

Comment: Shouldn't this include --continue as well?

Comment: @sfyn: Yes, I added `-c` to the answer so if anything fails you can pick up where you left off. Thanks.

Comment: It's better than any 3rd party download manager!